# calculating an initial website download?

Tags: web, measurement

hey guys,
weird question - i have no idea how to describe what i want i in the title of this question.
i wonder how i can measure or query how much megabytes or kilobytes my browser has to download to view my front-page of my website.

i'm trying to optimize my website for mobile devices and so i wonder how much bytes a mobile browser has to download to view my website. images, js-files, css-files, etc. all in all -> is there a nice and simple way to measure that?

thank you for your help
regards matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use web-browser developer tool.

For Chrome, tools are embedded in the browser:

- http://www.chromium.org/devtools/google-chrome-developer-tools-tutorial

For Firefox you can use the Firebug plugin:

- http://getfirebug.com/network

Comment: `FireBug` for FireFox is a must, as well. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/

Comment: thank you, didn't know firebug can do that. using firebug for years :)